# How to project an identical listview in one activity onto a popupwindow in another activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

In my loginpage for my game I have made it so that you can type in your player name and this is listed in a listview below.
(https://gyazo.com/19ab8f8af96ad6a304b4116e48d47dfc
Within my gamescreen (2nd activity) I have made a pop up window for the highscores.

My question: How can I copy that same identical list that is created within the loginpage of player names to my popupwindow within the 2nd activity screen.

This is how the pop up window looks like: 
https://gyazo.com/a03f3e79c521cdea151fec769b34da8e

Because I already have had to pass data from the list to my 2nd activity I have created the following:

```
public void openActivity2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gamescreen.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("names", list);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Now this is how I have made the pop up window (and I have attempted to get the list from the intent)

```
highscores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.highscores, null);

            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 1150, 1500, true);
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(constraintLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 140, 395);
            Intent iin= getIntent();
            list= iin.getStringArrayListExtra("names");
            if(list!=null)
            {
                scores=list;
            }
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Get the list from Activity 1 to Activity 2?

Comment: get the list and project it into a popupwindow made within the 2nd activity (explained above)

Comment: Basically the pop up window will be my highscores list, but for that to work, I need to project my listview within that popup window for the highscores

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.... be more clear please, You have a List in your Activity 1 then you want to get it from Activity 2 (The same list) and then you want it to populate on an alert / dialog?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS  editted my question

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS. ^ i hav

Comment: Is an ArrayList<String>? or ArrayList<SomeObject>?